# Edittext field getting cut off in RelativeLayout at run time

Tags: android, android-studio

So when I go to preview in Android Studio's preview tool, I get a layout that looks like:   [image]
Exactly how it should look, and all is good. However at run time, the first field appears to get somewhat cut off and looks like so:
[image]
Any text you attempt to enter does not show, not even partially, and I have no idea what is going on. XML below, the space was an attempted fix and I don't believe it is part of the problem since the problem was there before I added the element, and also it has no bearing on the positioning of other elements no matter what I try.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@android:color/white"
tools:context=".RegisterFragment">

<Space
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tempSpace"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextUsername"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editTextPassword"
    android:layout_below="@id/tempSpace"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/tempSpace"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/tempSpace"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editTextForename"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextUsername"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextUsername" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextForename"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Forename "
    android:layout_above="@+id/editTextSurname"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextPassword"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextPassword" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextSurname"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Surname"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextForename"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextForename"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editTextEmail" />



<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editTextAge"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextPassword"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextPassword" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextAge"
    android:hint="Age"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextEmail"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextEmail" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextAge"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextSurname"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextSurname" />
```

`

Comment: Start from the top to place widgets and don't use layout_above for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation=”vertical”
tools:context=".RegisterFragment">

<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:id="@+id/editTextUsername"
android:hint="Username">

<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textPassword"
android:ems="10"
android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
android:hint="Password"
/>

<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/editTextForename"
android:hint="Forename "
/>

<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/editTextSurname"
android:hint="Surname"/>

<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
android:ems="10"
android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
android:hint="Email"
/>

<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="number"
android:ems="10"
android:id="@+id/editTextAge"
android:hint="Age"
/>

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Register"
android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```